# キーボードの上に表示されているツールバーを非表示にするには、

Tags: monaca

キーボードの上に表示されているDoneなどが書かれているツールバーを非表示にするにはios/confing.xml　に`<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true"/>`
を追加すればいいとあったのでやってみたのですが、うまく行きません。どうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score -1):

自分も使ってみたのですが、CordovaのバグでiOSではうまく動かないようです。
こっちに乗り換えたという人が多いみたいです。MonacaでもGoldプラン以上だと組み込めると思います。

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

Comment: やはりプラグインで解決するしかないようですね。Goldプランに入ります！